# How do I check if a name already exists in SQLite3 using php?

Tags: php, sqlite, file-upload

I have a web form where a user can upload photos:

```
<?php
    session_save_path(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . '/sessions/');
    session_name('Image'); //Set a session name for all php files
    session_start(); //Start a session
?>
        <div id="wrap">
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="
            post">
                <input type="file" name="image_file"/>
                </br>
                <label for="title">IMAGE TITLE:</label>
                <input type="text" name="image_title" value=""/>
                <label for="name">YOUR NAME:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
                </br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="upload_submit" />
            </form>
            </br></br>
        </div>
```

That looks like:

[image]

The user uploads a photo and and set the image title, and I need to check if the image title exists in SQLite3 using php. After the user clicks `Submit`, they are directed to `upload.php` page and the page displays the image if the title does not exist or the page displays a message saying that the image already exists.

How do I check the image title already exists in SQLite3 databases?

Here is my `index.php` so far:

```
<?php
    session_save_path(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . '/sessions/');
    session_name('Image'); //Set a session name for all php files
    session_start(); //Start a session
?>
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['upload_submit']) ){ // they did submit
        if(isset($_POST['image_title']) && !empty($_POST['image_title']) AND isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
            try{
                $mydb = new SQLite3('image.db'); //creates the database
            }catch(Exception $ex){
                echo $ex->getMessage();
            }
            $fileName = $_FILES['image_file']['image_title'];
            $saveLocation = dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . '/uploads/' . $fileName;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $saveLocation);
            $image_title=trim(($_POST['image_title']));
            $user_name = trim(($_POST['name']));
                    
            $statement='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images(title TEXT NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL);';
                    
            $run = $mydb->query($statement);
            
            $_SESSION['image_title']= $image_title;
            $_SESSION['user_name']=$user_name;
            
            $statement = "INSERT INTO images (title,name) VALUES ('$image_title','$user_name');";
            $run = $mydb->query($statement);
            
            $statement = "SELECT from images WHERE title='$image_title';";
            $run = $mydb->query($statement);
            
            //if the image exists,
            $_SESSION['exist'] = true;
            header('Location: upload.php');

            //if the image exists,
            $_SESSION['exist'] = false;
            header('Location: upload.php');
        }
        else{
            echo 'Please fill in the information.';
        }
        
    }
?>
```

And Here is my `upload.php`:

```
<?php
    session_save_path(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . '/sessions/');
    session_name('Image'); //Set a session name for all php files
    session_start(); //Start a session
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['exist']) or !$_SESSION['exist']) {//image does not exist, display. ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Thank You, <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name'];?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Your image has been uploaded.</p>
    </br>
    <?php//Display image here
        echo "<img src= $_SESSION['image_title']'" . $_SESSION['saveLocation'] . "'>"; ?>
</body>
</html> <?php
    }
    else { //photo does exist ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Thank You, <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name'];?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><?php echo 'A photo named', $_SESSION['image_title'], ' by ', $_SESSION['user_name'],' already exists.';?> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `session_start()` in all this?

Comment: ```session_start();``` is in the first lane of the file.

Comment: All the files? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: I have added the lines to my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could query database as such

```
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT image_title FROM img WHERE image_title =:title');
$statement->bindValue(':title',$image_title , SQLITE3_TEXT);
$result = $statement->execute();
$assoc=$result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC));
If($assoc)
{
    ///Record found, do something
else
{
    ///Record not found, do something
}
```

So what it does basically does is check for **$assoc**, now I have worked with MySQL with php but it should be the same here as well, when you check for `if($assoc)` if the statement executed successfully and the object was found it will return an associative array meaning that the record was found, but if it returns a Boolean value i.e. false this would mean that no record was found based on condition in statement...
As I said I worked with only MySQL alongside PHP, so I don't know if this is an optimal solution but I think it will do the job

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use SQLiteStudio to check your database, table, and query structures, you can also test your applications by tracking their data changes.

There is more than one solution:

1.- You could easily define the image title as unique, by this way you'll make sure every title will be different.

2.- Encapsulate your validation logic in a function that returns false if an image with the same title already exists.

3.- If you don't go for the first option, first make your SELECT to check if an image with the provided title already exists, if not exists then perform an INSERT query, if not, return a false or showing the photo does exist.

4.- the fourth solution and the one I just prefer is make an HTML page, with JQuery, make an $.ajax HTTP POST request to your PHP file, catch the HTTP validating isset($_POST), do your procedure, validate if the title exists with a select, if not, do an insert, and return a positive response, if the title already exists,
return a message or response that indicates about this situation, handle the response in your JavaScript file, and show the result into your HTML file.

I hope could help you, if you want some more specific help just ask me.

Comment: Please update your answer and add a link to SQLiteStudio, provide some helpful example code for all of your options. Just saying "create a select" doesn't help that much if the question is exactly how to write a query or find this specific record.